# White text on some system windows

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce, gtk, xfwm4

I get white text on most windows, (it switches to its regular color when the said window loses focus).

I'm using a windows dual boot xubuntu 12.04 with xfce, xfwm, and a GTK theme 'zukiwi'. Can someone please help me sort this out?

Screenshots of the issue:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Hs5.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ4OD.png]

The problem is common with most windows that relate to some kind of system / core task.

Also, here is the gtkrc-2.0 file that I'm using:

```
#desktop icon transparency tweak
style "xfdesktop-icon-view" {
    XfdesktopIconView::label-alpha = 0

    base[NORMAL] = "#000000"
    base[SELECTED] = "#0071FF"
    base[ACTIVE] = "#0071FF"

    fg[NORMAL] = "#EEEEEE"
    fg[SELECTED] = "#3A3A3A"
    fg[ACTIVE] = "#3A3A3A"
    text[NORMAL] = "#262626"
    XfdesktopIconVIew::cell-spacing = 0
    XfdesktopIconView::cell-padding = 0
    XfdesktopIconView::cell-text-width-proportion = 2.0

}
#widget_class "*XfdesktopIconView*" style "xfdesktop-icon-view"
#Fixes the Panel color to a dull grey
#style "panel"
#{
#    font_name = "Segoe UI Regular 8"
#    bg[NORMAL] = "#222222"
#    fg[NORMAL] = "#323232"
#}
#
#widget_class "*Panel*"      style "panel"
#widget "*Panel*"            style "panel"
#class "*Panel*"             style "panel"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this line:

```
fg[NORMAL] = "#EEEEEE"
```

Try changing the color to something darker like #333 or #000 for black.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!
The issue still persists after changing `fg[NORMAL] = "#333333"` This affects only the Tcolour of my desktop icon text. Are there any other files that I can provide, that might help solve this?

Comment: @VaibhavYenamandra How about the gtkrc-3.0 file?

Comment: Can't find one in ~
Any other places I should look?

Comment: Also, will the files of current WM theme and GTK theme help?

Comment: Can you try this location: `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` or `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtk.css`..

Comment: No such file, however.

Think the theme's gtk is the issue:
(If zips are ok):

gtk-2.0 folder: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07229687285410886845

gtk-3.0 folder: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=96051263155611540740

Virus scan proofs so that I'm not taken for an attacker:
http://scanurl.net/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fs000.tinyupload.com%2Findex.php%3Ffile_id%3D96051263155611540740&uesb=Check+This+URL#results

and

http://scanurl.net/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fs000.tinyupload.com%2Findex.php%3Ffile_id%3D07229687285410886845&uesb=Check+This+URL#results

Comment: Registering this issue with the theme author. Thank you @Parlo